# OutOfMemoryError in Android Parse Integration

Tags: parse-platform

Here is the stack trace and it happens many times. Can't figure out what is happening this. Any help from parse.com experts? Would love to know what is there in line 316 of ParseCommand class. Dont have the source unfortunately.

```
0java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
1at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:255)
2at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:171)
3at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:141)
4at com.parse.ParseCommand.onResponse(ParseCommand.java:316)
5at com.parse.ParseCommand.onResponse(ParseCommand.java:33)
6at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.call(ParseRequest.java:267)
7at com.parse.Task$3.run(Task.java:199)
8at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
9at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Can't find that. This is all available in the Stack Trace. Happens randomly and found from logcat. Easy guess is when some sync with Parse is happening.

Comment: Happens when I am not interacting with the app also. I have SyncAdapter synching data. Would love to know what is there in line 316 of ParseCommand class. Dont have the source unfortunately.

Comment: So this problem goes away if you uninstall your app from device?

Comment: How do you expect people to help with the problem, if you don't show any code or even describe what the app does?

Comment: @SME_Dev, sorry, as I told, I am looking for help from Parse.com folks to see why this happens in their code and what is going on in line 316 of ParseCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am able to resolve this. All I did is some code clean up and avoided some crowded calls for Parse. This eliminated two simultaneous calls to Parse APIs in different threads.

Once the number of calls are limited, this error stopped showing.